# Is there any way to get New/Unread tweets count related to specific user?

Tags: php, twitter

I want to get new tweets count of a user, and i am using following documentation

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

but i don't see new count related any parameter here, any one guide me is it possible or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but that page says: "Version 1 of the API is now deprecated. This document may describe an outdated version of the API. Please move to Version 1.1 of the API as soon as possible."

Comment: Version 1.1 has that functionality? i am using updated version

Comment: Then you should be looking at the 1.1 docs, not the 1.0 docs :)
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: as per my knowledge this functionality is not available in the current api.